# equality operator == not working correctly

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I'm trying to write a simple text-based game. Everything seems to be working. At the end, I want to add an option to play again. I put the whole thing in a loop and at the end, I added:

```py
again = input('Would you like to play again? (Y/N) ')
if again == "Y" or "y":
    continue
else:
    break
```

Input seems to be storing the correct input but when compared to `'Y' or 'y'` returns true no matter what the input is.

I confirmed that the input is correct. Edited the code to visualize it better.

```
again = input('Would you like to play again? (Y/N) ')
print(again)
if again == "Y" or "y":
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

This was the output which didn't make sense to me.

```py
Would you like to play again? (Y/N) n
n
True
```

Comment: `==` is working fine; you are using `or` incorrectly.

Comment: Your statement is parsed `if (again == "Y") or ("y"):`, and the string "y" is always true.  Instead, do `if again in 'Yy':` or `if again.lower() == 'y':`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
if again == "Y" or "y":
```

to:

```
if again == "Y" or again == "y":
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if again == 'Y' or again == 'y':
```

Comment: Answers that are code-only with no explanation are not generally acceptable.